# MongoDB + nodejs : how to query ISODate fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, isodate

I am using nodejs with the node-mongodb-native driver (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/).

I have documents with a date property stored as `ISODate` type.

Through nodejs, I am using this query:

```
db.collection("log").find({
    localHitDate: { 
            '$gte': '2013-12-12T16:00:00.000Z',
            '$lt': '2013-12-12T18:00:00.000Z' 
    }
})
```

It returns nothing. To make it work I need to do the following instead:

```
db.collection("log").find({
    localHitDate: {
            '$gte': ISODate('2013-12-12T16:00:00.000Z'),
            '$lt': ISODate('2013-12-12T18:00:00.000Z')
    }
})
```

But `ISODate` is not recognized in my nodejs code.

So how can I make a query against mongo date fields through my nodejs program?

Thank you

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can use `new Date('2013-12-12T16:00:00.000Z')` in `node.js`;

**`new`** is a must, because Date() is already use to return date string.

ISODate is concepted in mongodb, you can use it in mongodb console, but it can be different for different programming language.

Comment: im really having a super difficult time with this...  i cant seem to store a utc isodate in mongo to save my life... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874993/javascript-momentjs-convert-utc-from-string-to-date-object

Comment: Thank you for the answer. saved lot of time

Comment: is the 12 a month or day?

Answer (score 11):

You can use this, for me worked perfectly

```
//lets require/import the mongodb native drivers.
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

//We need to work with "MongoClient" interface in order to connect to a mongodb server.
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// Connection URL. This is where your mongodb server is running.
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/klevin';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    //HURRAY!! We are connected. :)
    console.log('Connection established to', url);


    // Get the documents collection
    var collection = db.collection('frames');

    //We have a cursor now with our find criteria
    var cursor = collection.find({
      tv: 'tematv', 
      date_created: {"$gte": new Date("2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z") , "$lt": new Date("2017-03-13T16:17:36.470Z") }});

    //We need to sort by age descending
    cursor.sort({_id: -1});

    //Limit to max 10 records
    cursor.limit(50);

    //Skip specified records. 0 for skipping 0 records.
    cursor.skip(0);


    //Lets iterate on the result
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {

      if (err) {

        console.log(err);

      } else {

        console.log('Fetched:', doc);

        if(doc !== null){ 

        }

      }
    });


  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to use **new Date()** is best option to get the data.

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      $and: [
        {
          status: 'UNASSIGNED'
        },
        {
          plannedDeliveryDate: {
            '$eq': new Date('2017-10-09')
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "servicelocations",
      localField: "serviceLocationId",
      foreignField: "serviceLocationId",
      as: "locations"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$locations"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "accountId": 1,
      "orderId": 1,
      "serviceLocationId": 1,
      "orderDate": 1,
      "description": 1,
      "serviceType": 1,
      "orderSource": 1,
      "takenBy": 1,
      "plannedDeliveryDate": 1,
      "plannedDeliveryTime": 1,
      "actualDeliveryDate": 1,
      "actualDeliveryTime": 1,
      "deliveredBy": 1,
      "size1": 1,
      "size2": 1,
      "size3": 1,
      "jobPriority": 1,
      "cancelReason": 1,
      "cancelDate": 1,
      "cancelBy": 1,
      "reasonCode": 1,
      "reasonText": 1,
      "status": 1,
      "lineItems": 1,
      "locations": {
        "lng": "$locations.location.lng",
        "lat": "$locations.location.lat"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through my answer, provided in other asked question.

Their instead of $eq use $gte:"yyyy-mm-dd", $lte:"yyyy-mm-dd"

[NodeJS MongoDB: Querying ISO Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717323/nodejs-mongodb-querying-iso-date/63298056#63298056)

Hope this will help you or somebody else!