# Javascript momentjs convert UTC from string to Date Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

Folks,
  Having a difficult time with moment.js documentation.

```
record.lastModified = moment.utc().format();
```

returns:

```
2014-11-11T21:29:05+00:00
```

Which is Great, its in UTC...  When I store that in Mongo, it gets stored as a `String`, not a `Date` object type, which is what i want.

What I need it to be is:

```
"lastModified" : ISODate("2014-11-11T15:26:42.965-0500")
```

But I need it to be a **native** javascript object type, and store that in Mongo.  Right now if i store the above, it goes in as string, not Date object type.

I have tried almost everything with moment.js.  Their toDate() function works, but falls back to my local timezone, and not giving me utc.

Thanks!

Comment: The `toDate()` function that you mention is what you want here. JavaScript `Date` objects always internally represent their time in UTC. Can you edit your question with the details on why you think that's not working?

Comment: Try `new Date(moment.utc().format());`

Comment: I am having the same issue, been at this for hours

Answer (score 5):

Saving a Javascript `Date` object will result in an `ISODate` being stored in Mongo.

Saving an ISO date as a Javascript `String` will result in a `String` being stored in Mongo.

So, this is what you want: `record.lastModified = new Date(moment().format());`

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution, But I achieved the same result, by manually converting it to ISODate object through monogo shell. We need the ISODate for comparison/query for aggregating results, so we run this script before running our aggregate scripts.

Inserting local time string by using moment().format().

```
"createdDt" : "2015-01-07T17:07:43-05:00"`
```

Converting to an ISODate (UTC) with:

```
    var cursor = db.collection.find({createdDt : {$exists : true}});
    while (cursor.hasNext()){
        var doc = cursor.next();
        db.collection.update(
                   {_id : doc._id}, 
                   {$set: {createdDt : new ISODate(doc.createdDt)}})
    }
```

results in

```
"createdDt" : ISODate("2015-01-07T22:07:43Z")"
```

Note the time got converted
`T17:07:43-05:00` to `T22:07:43Z`

I could not find any solution for inserting BSON ISODate format (which is UTC by default) from JavaScript directly, while inserting a new document, it seems to be available through pyMongo & C#/Java Drivers though. Trying to look for an maintainable solution