# aggregate match returns null with $gte and $lt

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using the following code to retrieve the data from mongodb. Somehow when I added the `$match` to the code it returns empty set. Without it I get my results fine so there is no any other error. What can be the error in `$match` . How can I fix it ?

This is the code in my API?

```
postSchemaModel.aggregate([{
            "$geoNear": {
                "near": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [parseFloat(long), parseFloat(lat), ] },
                "distanceField": "dist.calculated",
                "maxDistance": parseInt(maxDistance),
                "includeLocs": "dist.location",
                "spherical": true
            }
        },
        // mactchString,
        {
            "$match": {
                "createdAt": {
                    "$gte": '2020-07-15 23:54:38.673665',
                    "$lt": '2020-06-15 23:54:38.673665'
                }
            }
        },
        { "$limit": limit },
        { "$skip": startIndex },
        { "$sort": { "createdAt": -1 } },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": userSchemaModel.collection.name,
                "localField": "user_id",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "user_id"
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "post_data": 1,
                "likes": 1,
                "commentsCount": 1,
                "post_img": 1,
                "isUserLiked": 1,
                "usersLiked": 1,
                'exp_date': 1,
                "has_img": 1,
                "user_id": {
                    "img": "$user_id.img",
                    "_id": "$user_id._id",
                    "user_name": "$user_id.user_name",
                    "bday": "$user_id.bday",
                    "imagesource": "$user_id.imagesource",
                    "fb_url": "$user_id.fb_url",
                },
                "typology": 1,
                "geometry": 1,
                "category": 1,
                "created": 1,
                "createdAt": 1,
                "updatedAt": 1,
            }
        },
    ]).then(async function(posts) {
        //some code here
        }
    });
```

The following is a sample post from mongodb
[image]

What can be the error here. How can I fix it ?

Comment: When you pass date in the match, is it the string or a date instance?

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa I tried using `"$gte": '2020-07-15 23:54:38.673665'` and also 
`"$gte": Date.parse('2020-07-15 23:54:38.673665')`

Comment: Try passing date constructor.

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa Still the same !

Comment: Try new Date().toISOString()

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa tried but no success :(

`"$match": {
                    "createdAt": {
                        "$gte": new Date('2020-07-15 23:54:38.673665').toISOString(),
                        "$lt": new Date('2020-06-15 23:54:38.673665').toISOString()
                    }
                }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the date field in `new Date()` similar to this

```js
"$match": {
  "createdAt": {
    "$gte": new Date('2020-07-15T23:54:38.673Z'),
    "$lt": new Date('2020-06-15T23:54:38.673Z')
   }
}
```

Check [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561381/mongodb-nodejs-how-to-query-isodate-fields).

Comment: ISODate is a part of MongoDB if I use it here it gives me ***ISODate is not defined***. In this case I can use `Date()` but it give me the same empty result set

Comment: Sorry my bad. Try sending date in ISO date format eg: `2020-07-15T23:54:38.673Z`. This should work.

Comment: Tried ! But the same result

Comment: It's still a `string`. We should tell `mongodb` that it's a `date` I guess. `new Date('2020-07-15T23:54:38.673Z')` is [the right one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20561843/13907595). Updated my answer.