# How to query in array of object based on Date in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So i have this collection store in mongo DB:

```
 Exercise Records

 {
      username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },

      count: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      },

      log: [{
          description: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        duration: {
          type: Number,
          required: true
        },
        date: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        }
      }]
 }
```

This is what I do to retrieve the document based on ID:

```
let userExerciseData = Exercise.findOne({_id: id}});
```

Then, I return with `res.send(userExerciseData)`.

Output:

```
{
    "_id":"62d68cc5a586035962e18115",
    "username":"paranoid_android99",
    "count":3,
    "log": [
       {"description":"Build triceps & biceps muscle","duration":120,"date":"Tue Jul 19 2022"}, 
       {"description":"Leg workouts","duration":30, "date":"Thu Jul 21 2022"},
       {"description":"Burning calories","duration":60, "date":"Thu Jul 28 2022"},
       {"description":"Plank","duration":60, "date":"Fri Jul 01 2022"}
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get all documents BUT **WHERE** the `log` is only contain object **WHERE** the date is from `Fri Jul 01 2022` to `Thu Jul 21 2022`. Which will not include `{"description":"Burning calories","duration":60, "date":"Thu Jul 28 2022"}`

And this is what I'm trying to do:

```
const from = new Date('2022-07-01').toDateString();
const to = new Date('2022-07-21').toDateString();

let exerciseDataByLogs = await Exercise.findOne({
    log: {
        $elemMatch: {
            // This doesn't work
            date: {$gt: from, $lt: to}
        }
     }
 })
            
 console.log(exerciseDataByLogs); // return NULL
 res.send(exerciseDataByLogs); // return NULL
```

But somehow it's always return `NULL`. So what is wrong with my code?

I hope you guys understand. Thank You.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this other question about [querying `ISODate` fields in MongoDB from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20561381/656011).

Comment: @EricAllen I still can't understand. I'm very new in this. I need explanation. Like what is wrong with my code

Comment: You should **never** store date values as strings, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. Then the query is simply `from = new Date('2022-07-01')`